# python pygeos cant import DLL

Tags: python, dll, importerror, geopandas

When I install pygeos it wont install correctly

Try and load this:

```
>> from pygeos.lib import GEOSException
```

got DLL not found

Comment: Worked for me with no change.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding the environment variable:

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pygeos